# Translate C++ code that uses char type to Python

Tags: python, c++

How would this code look like in python? `nrComm1->SendChar` can be replaced with `serial.write(A_CHAR)`

```
void prepare()
{
    char temp[50];
    sprintf(temp,"%04XT2000A", 76);

    send(temp);
}

void send(char *TX_String)
{
    unsigned char checksum = 0x02;  

    nrComm1->SendChar(0x02);
    while(*TX_String)
    {
        nrComm1->SendChar(*TX_String);
        checksum ^= *TX_String++;
    }
    nrComm1->SendChar(0x03);
    checksum ^= 0x03;                            

    nrComm1->SendChar(checksum);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look something like this (not a working example, just to get you started):

Update: provided hints how to make the example work...

```
def prepare():
    temp = "%04XT2000A" % 76
    send(temp)


def send(tx_string):
    checksum = 0x02
    serial.write(checksum)

    # hint: int conversion will not work since tx_string is a
    # string representation of a hex value, add conversion code for this
    while(tx_string):
        serial.write(int(tx_string[0]))
        checksum = checksum ** int(tx_string[0])
        tx_string = tx_string[1:]

    serial.write(0x03)
    checksum = checksum ** 0x03
    serial.write(checksum)
```

Comment: I get 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: On what line? I didn't say this is a working example, i didn't test it, its just a draft version to get you thinking for your self. But i guess i did spoonfeeding instead... Give it some more effort.